# awk / sed: replace all fields if any field matches a pattern

Tags: unix, awk, sed, replace

I have a tab-delimited file with at least 16 (but might be more) columns, where the first column is an unique identifier; and >10,000 rows (only 6x6 shown in example), like this:

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    4    4     4     -9    4
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    6    -9    6     6     6
```

I need to change all values of VAR1-5 into "-9" if one of the values is already "-9"

So, the desired output would be:

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
```

So far, I've tried doing this in awk like this:

```
awk -F'\t' '
BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if ($i=="-9"){for(j=2;j<=NF;j++){$j="-9"};continue}}};1
' < file1.tab
```

Which works, but is very slow when applied to the actual dataset. Is there a faster way to do this? Perhaps something with a combination of `grep` and `sed`?

Comment: If you are already using Awk, it does everything `sed` and `grep` can do, and often faster.

Comment: *all values of VAR1-5* - should it process only the first 5 columns?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest The OP's own attempt seems to confirm the suspicion that it should actually replace all the columns. I updated the title to reflect this, so please rollback if this was an incorrect interpretation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a variation which doesn't hard-code the number of columns.

```
awk -F '\t' '/(^|\t)-9(\t|$)/ {
    printf $1; for(i=2; i<=NF; ++i) printf "\t-9"; printf "\n"
    next }
  1' file1 file2
```

The main optimization here is that Awk scans the entire line at once and triggers on the regex immediately, without needing to loop over all the fields unless it already knows that there is a match.

Because we know we will ditch all the fields except the first, there is no need to have Awk replace the fields so that it can then print them. Just generate the output we want to print and move on without touching Awk's internal representation of the line.  This should buy a couple of cycles as well, though this is a very minor performance improvement.

Comment: why multiple files `file1 file2` in this concrete case?

Comment: Just to show that it can be done really. Do you think it's confusing?

Comment: for me and you it won't be very critical, but it may confuse some less "experienced eyes"

Comment: Thanks for the comment -- hoping that leaving the comments here is sufficient *caveat emptor* (-:

Answer (score 3):

Following `awk` may help you in same, I have tested it with your provided sample.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} /(^|\t)-9(\t|$)/{print $1,"-9   -9    -9    -9    -9";next} 1' OFS="    "   Input_file
```

In case OP has more than 5 fields or so in Input_file then following may help, logic is same as triple sir's solution, where I am traversing through fields but in spite of printing `-9` I am assigning the field's values to `-9`.

```
awk 'FNR==1{print;next} /(^|\t)-9(\t|$)/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=-9};} 1' OFS="\t\t"   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation to above code too now.

```
awk '
FNR==1{                ##Checking condition here if line number is 1 then do following:
  print;               ##Printing the current line then which will be very first line of Input_file.
  next                 ##next is awk out of the box keyword which will skip all further statements for program.
}
/(^|\t)-9(\t|$)/{        ##Checking here if -9 is coming in a line either with spaces or without spaces, if yes then do following:
  print $1,"-9   -9    -9    -9    -9";  ##printing the first field of current line along with 5 -9 values as per OPs request to do so.
  next                 ##next will skip all further statements.
}
1                      ##awk works on method of condition then action, so I am making condition TRUE here by mentioning 1 here and not mentioning action here so by default print of the current line will happen.
' OFS="    " Input_file   ##Setting OFS(output field separator) value to spaces and mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `/-9/` alone will already match everything that `/ +-9 +/` matches, so the condition seems oddly overcomplicated. The regex in my answer searches for -9 alone in a field; maybe take that regex instead.

Comment: Also, special-casing `FNR==1` is probably not strictly necessary, though it's a useful reminder to at least think about whether the first line should be treated specially. (Not having column headings is often what we Unix-heads prefer.)

Comment: 1) typo - extra single quote in the awk command... 2) since input is tab-delimited, why not use `OFS="\t"` 3) OP mentions that input has more columns than shown in sample, so generic solution is needed

Comment: @Sundeep, apologies that `'` single quote came while copying triple's regex which I overlooked. For generic solution let me see if I could create one and could post it then, thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Then you'll end up duplicating my answer (-:

Comment: @tripleee, Sir: added solution(logic is same as yours) only thing in spite of printing fields I am assigning them value to `-9`. Though thinking still if I could have some other way too here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r '/-9/s/[^ ]+/-9/2g' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    -9    -9     -9     -9    -9
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    -9    -9    -9     -9     -9
```

Comment: Maybe note that `-r` is a non-portable extension which enables (a variant of) extended regular expressions; a similar option `-E` may be available on some other platforms. This can easily be rephrased as a portable script, though it will then be somewhat more clunky (you have to replace any `x+` with `xx*` or perhaps `x\+`).

Comment: The thing between `[^...]` should be a literal tab. In many shells, tab is bound to completion in interactive use, but you can type <ctrl-v> <tab> to get a literal tab character on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Some more way using **GNU awk**

**One-liner:**

```
awk '/(^|[ \t]+)-9([ \t]+|$)/{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$0=gensub (/[^[:blank:]]+/,-9,i)}1' infile
```

**Better Readable :**

```
awk '/(^|[ \t]+)-9([ \t]+|$)/{
       for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
            $0=gensub (/[^[:blank:]]+/,-9,i)
     }1
    ' infile
```

**Test Results:**

***Input:***

```
$ cat infile
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    4    4     4     -9    4
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    6    -9    6     6     6
```

***Output:***

( because of `-` spacing shifted )

```
$ awk '/(^|[ \t]+)-9([ \t]+|$)/{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$0 = gensub (/[^[:blank:]]+/, -9 , i)}1' infile  
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4    -9    -9     -9     -9    -9
5    5    5     5     5     5
6    -9    -9    -9     -9     -9
```

***If you want output to look better may try this : ( not recommended )***

```
awk '/(^|[ \t]+)-9([ \t]+|$)/{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){ if($i==-9)continue; $0 = gensub (/[^[:blank:]]+/, "\b-9" , i)}}1' infile  
ID  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4  VAR5
1    1    1     1     1     1
2    -9   -9    -9    -9    -9
3    3    3     3     3     3
4   -9   -9    -9     -9   -9
5    5    5     5     5     5
6   -9    -9   -9    -9    -9
```

***Better readable version of above :***

```
awk '/(^|[ \t]+)-9([ \t]+|$)/{
          for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)
          { 
            if($i==-9)continue; 
            $0 = gensub(/[^[:blank:]]+/, "\b-9" , i)
          }
     }1
    ' infile
```

Comment: Why the loop? Just `gsub(/\t[^\t]*/, "\t-9")` should do it.

Comment: @tripleee you are right, but not sure about OP's original input, since OP said `VAR1-5` I was about to make `i<=6` instead of `i<=NF`, felt current context its fine, used gensub in loop to retain original spacing , and with `/(^|\t)-9(\t|$)/` and sample i/p I didn't receive expected o/p

Comment: The sample looks like it's space-delimited but the OP describes it as tab-delimited so you probably have to adjust the sample slightly.

Comment: Yes, thanks I will check and adjust once I am back to my seat.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{IFS=OFS="    "}/-9/{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){$i=-9}}1' filename
```

Comment: While this might be correct and solve the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here, so that future visitors can learn from the OP's mistakes.